# R Iterate a calculation from a variable

Tags: r, database, pandas, data-science

I have a data base of postal code.
I want to create for each postal code, 4 variables which are the year, the month, the day and the hour from 01.01.2008 to 30.06.2008
The goal is to create an indicator that calculate a number of alarms that have been pulled.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried, you've also included `r` and `pandas` here so which is it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this :

for (elt in c$CP) 
 For each elt do

```
     time_index=seq(from = as.POSIXct("2008-01-01 00:00"),
     to = as.POSIXct("2016-06-30 23:00"), by = "hour"))
```

At the end i want a unique database where i have 2 column CP (postal code) and time_index
I will have to append each data base to make it unique

Comment: This should be an edit to your question rather than a answer, in order to help others so they can help you post raw data, for example a few lines of your data plus your code above, and the desired output, it helps if you show how it should look and the format rather than just describe it, thanks